# Model validate method returns error from server rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method in my `micropost.rb`, the error is souly when I run this method. When I submit my form I do not get the errors from the model but the rendering of the `else` condition in the **controller**. Something seems to be wrong in the **model** but don't see why I get rollback transaction from server?

The method just checks that a user has not entered and sent more than one field.

**Micropost.rb**

```
validate :return_media_field_errors

private 

def return_media_field_errors
  if :img_url? && :video_url? 
    errors.add(:img_url, "Can only submit one field at a time")
  end
end
```

**MicropostController**

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
  if @micropost.save
    flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
    @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'static_pages/home'
  else
    @feed_items = []
    render 'shared/error_messages'
  end
end

private

  def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture, :picture_cache, :image_url, :video_url, :gif_url)
  end
```

**micropost schema.rb**

```
create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "content"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "picture"
  t.string   "image_url"
  t.string   "video_url"
  t.string   "gif_url"
  t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"
end
```

View params

```
<div class="media_field_1">    
  Image <%= f.text_field :image_url, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="media_field_2"> 
  Video <%= f.text_field :video_url, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems your validation is doing its job, just perhaps not what you expected. Can you show your strong params, the submitted params and your Micropost schema?

Comment: sure, added the code and view fields. If you want the form value it is a jpg starting with https, I have a pretty heafty method on those fields to change the dimensions on a before_create action.

Comment: You have a typo `img_url` must be `image_url`. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh man you be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
if :img_url? && :video_url?
```

here `:img_url?` is a symbol, not an attribute

What you want is `self.image_url?` or just `image_url`, same for `video_url`

Comment: I get a nomethoderror when I change it to this on those fields.

Comment: didn't notice the typo with `img`. Can you try again?

Comment: Aha. You got it! Thanks!